# How to configure .htaccess for MediaWiki connection http to https?

Tags: mediawiki

Can you help me with configuring an .htaccess file where I can redirect the connection from my mediawiki the http to https.

What should I include in the .htaccess file and what should I include in the LocalSettings.php file.

Thank you,

Enzo.

.htaccess configuracion file:

#BEGIN HTTPS Redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#END HTTPS Redirect